# Do I need to sanitize this field or is JPA doing that behind the scenes for me?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

This is my first project ever in Java so I'm not really sure how things work. I'm doing my best to learn, so if I say anything that is not right, please correct me.

For my project I'm using JavaFX. I'm taking a username from a TextField (so it's input from the user, which might not be safe) and on the server side I want to use this data in a WHERE clause, in a method in a DAO, using JPA.

Here's the method:

```java
public PersoanaEntity get(String username) throws NoResultException {
    return connection
            .getEntityManager()
            .createQuery("SELECT a FROM PersoanaEntity as a WHERE a.username = :username", PersoanaEntity.class)
            .setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
}
```

I'm not really sure that it is JPA though. I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between JPA and JDBC, but for what I've read, it seems like the method above is using a JPA.

So, am I safe to provide the username parameter from the user in this case?

Comment: Any serious JPA implementation will use prepared statements and parameters, which will protect against SQL injection. There is no sanitization (at least not within the JPA implementation), because that isn't necessary when using prepared statements and parameters. As an aside, JPA builds on (uses) JDBC.

Comment: What JPA implementation is currently used by the project? Hibernate?

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov jakarta.persistence, I think, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu, «Java Pesistence API» (JPA) was renamed to «Jakarta Persistence». Therefore, «Jakarta Persistence» is a specification itself, not an implementation of the specification. Please, see the page: [Jakarta Persistence | The Eclipse Foundation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/).

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu, taking this into account, there are two questions. 1. What version of «Jakarta Persistence» is used by the project? 2. What implementation of «Jakarta Persistence» is used by the project?

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov None of those questions are particularly relevant. Sanitization should not be not necessary when using JPA.